# Since I got here/came

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

Two strangers talk at a bar.

> You're on your fifth drink since I **got/came** here, so maybe you should
> slow down a bit.

What would be natural here? "Got here"? "Came"?

Comment: If this is dialog, then use "got here". It's informal and pretty common.

Answer (score 1):

"Got" is somewhat like "ain't": commonly used in casual speech, but frowned upon in formal writing.

I had an English teacher who would wield his red pen whenever he found a "got", then rant that it was not even a word. It is never necessary to use "got", so it can always be edited out of formal writing.

But I ain't gonna stop sayin' it.

Comment: Surely that's with reference to sentences like "I have got an apple" rather than to the past tense of "get here"?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably not natural for a person to give advice on how much a stranger should be drinking.

But you could use either "came here" or "got here", as both can mean "arrived".  "Got here" is natural in a casual, spoken context.

But "since I came, so maybe..."  would be wrong. You need the locative "here".